# Foundation Range Slider

Tags: html, user-interface, zurb-foundation, frontend

I need to use the foundation **Range Slider** component. The official docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html) say you need **foundation.slider.js** library for this to work. However, I can't find it anywhere on the site.
Its simply not there.

> This is really strange. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

So Range Slider is not available in Foundation 5 yet but the documentation is there. Weird. Though I managed to get it by tricking the UI to request it. But it's not working.
Now I have to use jQuery UI for the range slider, while everything else is using foundation.

> How hard is it to code a simple slider Zurb??

Answer (score 0):

Should be in the 5.2.2 download under the foundation directory.

/foundation/foundation.slider.js

What's not working for you Jabran?

Jw

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation
Still can't find it.

Comment: Download the complete library it's in there. Looks like Zurb hasn't added that component to the custom screen yet. It's in the issues over on [GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5062).